Formatting issues with PhpStorm for React/RN
I'm having issues with my PhpStorm settings where it's wrapping on save. I'm not seeing any setting that would allow me to prevent this. I've confirmed it's not Prettier or ESLint causing the issue.
Here what's happening with the code:
<View>
    <Text>Money</Text> <Button
    title="Open Drawer"
    onPress={() => console.log('Open Drawer')}
/>
</View>

and here what I'm expecting:
<View>
    <Text>Money</Text> 
    <Button
        title="Open Drawer"
        onPress={() => console.log('Open Drawer')}
    />
</View>

